# Using Stream API for organising application pipeline

Tags: java, java-8, pipeline

As far as I know Stream API is intended to be applied on collections. But I like the idea of them so much that I try to apply them when I can and when I shouldn't.

Originally my app had two threads communicating through `BlockingQueue`. First would populate new elements. Second make transformations on them and save on disk. Looked like a perfect stream oportunity for me at a time.

Code I ended up with:

```
Stream.generate().flatten().filter().forEach()
```

I'd like to put few `map`s in there but turns out I have to drag one additional field till `forEach`. So I either have to create meaningless class with two fields and obscure name or use `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` to carry both fields through, which doesn't look like a great deal to me.

Anyway I'd rewritten my app and it even seems to work. However there are some caveats. As I have infinite stream 'the thing' can't be stopped. For now I'm starting it on daemon thread but this is not a solution. Business logic (like on connection loss/finding, this is probably not BL) looks alienated. Maybe I just need proxy for this.

On the other hand there is free laziness with queue population. One thread instead of two (not sure how good is this). Hopefully familiar pattern for other developers.

So my question is how viable is using of Stream API for application flow organising? Is there more underwather roks? If it's not recomended what are alternatives?

Comment: You want to use `Stream` for some sort of online processing?

Comment: @SashaSalauyou I'm not sure what you mean by 'online processing'. Definition I found on the internet - method for taking product orders and dealing with payments. My application gets recent photos from instagram and saves them with certain transformations applied.

Comment: Aren't you aware that `BlockingQueue` stream won't truly consume items, just process items that are already located in the queue? I suppose that would cause memory leak after some time of application working. Another drawback is that you won't be able to discover, judging only by contents of the queue, which elements are already processed and which are not.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou I had queue only in original design to connect `supplier` and `consumer` which worked on different threads. With stream I don't have to synchronize as (again) I have only one thread `Stream.generate(suplier::get).forEach(consumer::accept)`.

Comment: It is unclear why you ever used a multi-threaded approach in the first place when all you wanted to do is a simple processing loop. If you just want a processing loop, using `Stream` is fine. But if there is a real reason to use a multi-threaded approach, that reason might make using `Stream`s hard or even impossible.

Comment: This seriously looks like your first approach with Blocking Queue was more appropriate.  Streams aren't designed to be used like this.

Comment: @Holger I've used multi-threaded approach because I have to controll frequency of calls to `suplier` and no such constraint on `consumer`.

Comment: @user2418306: but a consumer can’t consume anything unless the supplier provided something. So what is the *benefit* of using multiple threads over just feeding whatever the supplier produces into the consumer right afterwards within the same thread? After all, that’s what you will do when using a `Stream`, and you’re not only saying that using a single thread with a `Stream` is fine, but that using a single thread is *your intention* there. So why wasn’t it appropriate before using a `Stream`?

Comment: @Holger now it looks obvious now but not so apparent back then. I guess I'm just stupid. That's why I used two threads.

Comment: Then, it’s not a problem. As said, the original motivation for using a multi-threaded approach is important for judging whether a `Stream` based approach may have drawbacks. So it this case, using a `Stream` will work. However, I recommend to also try to implement a simple straight-forward loop solution to decide whether the `Stream` solution provides an actual *benefit* as not causing problems is not enough reason for using an API ;-)

Comment: @Holger What kind of *benefit* do you have in mind?