# Stream generate at fixed rate

Tags: java, java-8

I'm using `Stream.generate` to get data from Instagram. As instagram limits calls per hour I want `generate` to run less frequent then every 2 seconds.

I've chosen such title because I moved from `ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate` and that's what I was searching for. I do realise that stream intermediate operations are lazy and cannot be called on schedule. If you have better idea for title let me know.

So again I want to have at least 2 second delay between genations.

My attempt wich doesn't take into consideration time consumed by operations after `generate`, which might take longer then 2s:

```
Stream.generate(() -> {
            List<MediaFeedData> feedDataList = null;
            while (feedDataList == null) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    feedDataList = newData();
                } catch (InstagramException e) {
                    notifyError(e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return feedDataList;
        })
```

Comment: It doesn't really make sense. Why did you move away from `ScheduledExecutorService` if it worked for you?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30051309

Comment: What’s your question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67653546/force-a-wait-or-sleep-during-stream has a simple solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand, your question is about solving two problems:

- waiting at a fixed rate rather than a fixed delay
- creating a stream for an unknown number of items which allows processing until some point of time (i.e. is not infinite)

You can solve the first task by using a deadline-based waiting and the second by implementing a `Spliterator`:

```
Stream<List<MediaFeedData>> stream = StreamSupport.stream(
    new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<List<MediaFeedData>>(Long.MAX_VALUE, 0) {
        long lastTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
        @Override
        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super List<MediaFeedData>> action) {
            if(quitCondition()) return false;
            List<MediaFeedData> feedDataList = null;
            while (feedDataList == null) {
                lastTime+=TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2);
                while(System.currentTimeMillis()<lastTime)
                    LockSupport.parkUntil(lastTime);
                try {
                    feedDataList=newData();
                } catch (InstagramException e) {
                    notifyError(e.getMessage());
                    if(QUIT_ON_EXCEPTION) return false;
                }
            }
            action.accept(feedDataList);
            return true;
        }
    }, false);
```

Answer (score 4):

A solution would be to decouple the generator from the `Stream`, for example using a `BlockingQueue`

```
final BlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(100);

ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
    // Generate new data every 2s, regardless of their processing rate
    ThreadLocalRandom random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
    queue.offer(random.nextInt(10));
}, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Stream.generate(() -> {
    try {
        // Accept new data if ready, or wait for some more to be generated
        return queue.take();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    return -1;
}).forEach(System.out::println);
```

If the data processing takes more than 2s, new data will be enqueued and wait to be consumed. If it takes less than 2s, the `take` method in the generator will wait for new data to be produced by the scheduler.

This way, you are guaranteed to make less than N calls per hour to Instagram !

Answer (score 1):

Make a **Timer** and a semaphore. The timer raises the semaphore every 2 seconds, and in the stream you wait on every call for the semaphore.

This keeps the waits to the specified minimum (2 s), and - funnily - would even work with `.parallel()`.

```
private final volatile Semaphore tickingSemaphore= new Semaphore(1, true);
```

In its own thread:

```
Stream.generate(() -> {
     tickingSemaphore.acquire();
     ...
};
```

In the timer:

```
tickingSemaphore.release();
```