# Force a wait or sleep during stream

Tags: java, java-stream, scheduledexecutorservice

Let's say I have:

```
 list.stream()
     .map(someService::someRateLimitedApiCall) //does not implement Runnable
     .filter(Optional::isPresent)
     .map(Optional::get)
     .sleep(1000) //is something like this possible?
     .min...;
```

The API service only allows limited number of transactions per second, and I am seeking to introduce a delay in between calls.

If not, is there a way to add an executor with a fixed delay within the iteration of the stream?

(To be clear, I am not violating the terms of the external API and will not abuse the service.)

Comment: Is `list` the exhaustive number of API calls that you want to make? How about creating batches to dispatch them per sec to the service?

Comment: Have you tried with `peek`?

Comment: peek(Thread.sleep(x)) should do the trick, unless you use parallell streams. But for all the abuse of declarations questions, I cant answer.

Comment: @Naman, that would be a good alternative solution, though arguably a little more complex as I would imagine it.

Comment: The service itself ought to be handling rate-limiting; for example, what happens when multiple requests independently fire off streams?

Comment: `filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get)` can be shortened to `flatMap(Optional::stream)` (just an aside)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than use peek, why not just put the delay in the map operation which calls the API?

```
.map(e -> {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
    return someRateLimitedApiCall(e);
})
```

Comment: It would be better to move this code as a `Function<Optional<T>, T> waitAndCallService`, so that the stream would look nice and clean -> `map(waitAndCallService()).filter(............`

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution (without parallel streams) was to use `peek` as multiple commenters suggested.  Since it requires a `Consumer`:

```
.peek(i -> {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
})
```